# In Outlook for Mac is it possible to set "Respond Without Comments" to be my default when accepting an invite?

Tags: ms-office

As it is, the default action on the "Respond" button is "Respond with Comments" and I have to click the drop down to send the response without comments.

[image: Respond Without Comments]

> Please Respond.
> Accept | Tentative | Decline
>
> Respond With Comments
> Respond Without Comments
> Do Not Send a Response

99% of the time if I'm accepting an invite I don't need to comment.

I've looked through the Preferences for Outlook and I don't see anything related to this.

Comment: I think it's intentional on Microsoft's part to make the Mac experience as annoying as possible.

Comment: MS is like "Ohhhhh, some people use Macs? LOL k"

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyboard shortcut.
No way to reduce mouse clicks.